# ¿Es posible declarar dos clases con el mismo serialVersionUID sin consecuencias?

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, netbeans-8.2, ejb

La pregunta es simple, estoy haciendo un desarrollo en JEE.

Y a cada ViewScoped le agrego la línea

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;
```

Para cada clase un serialVersionUID diferente.

Pero estoy mamado de estar cambiando ese pinche número, y me da vaina dejarles a todas las clases el mismo valor 1L.

Mi pregunta entones, ¿Se le puede dejar a todos los scoped `serialVersionUID=1L` sin tener consecuencias en la des-serialización? o lo sigo haciendo como lo he venido haciendo hasta el momento (ya voy en el 20L) y es cansón porque a   veces no recuerdo en que número iba (como NetBeans me organiza las clases alfabéticamente es complejo estar mire una por una)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `serialVersionUID` solo tiene sentido relativo a la misma clase.

Se usa para serializar la clase (por ejemplo al pasivizar, para guardarla en disco o pasarla entre distintos servidores). La serialización por defecto (puedes implementar la tuya propia), al deserializar (reconstruir) un objeto a partir de los datos serializado lo que hace es:

- Lee el nombre de la clase de los datos serializados y busca la implementación (el `.class`) entre las clases de la JVM. Si no lo encuentra da un error.
- Compara el `serialVersionUID` de la clase en la JVM con el `serialVersionUID` obtenido en los datos serializados. Si no coinciden, entiende que son distintas versiones de la misma clase, incompatibles entre sí, y lanza un error.
- Crea una instancia de la clase y va asignando los valores a los atributos. Si hay incompatibilidades (p.ej. en los datos serializados hay el valor de un campo que no existe en la clase de la JVM) da un error.

Así que sí, puedes usar el mismo `serialVersionUID` en clases distintas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es todo lo que necesitaba saber